# JTable: adding one dimensional array as rows

Tags: java, arrays, swing, jtable

`String[] names = app1.getSimplifiedMovieRecordsList();`

I have this string array with names of movies. I need to display this as the rows of a  table having one column. Can someone please tell me how to do this.

Comment: What display technology are you using? HTML (JSP, JSF, Velocity, etc.), Swing, SWT, console output, something else? Also, note that the 'table' tag you've used says not to use it, and the row tag applies to databases rather than displaying rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> need to display this as the rows of a table having one column

Presuming you mean `JTable` as your title suggests:

1. Convert the String array into a 2D array with names.length rows, and 1 column.
2. Create the column name array (length 1).
3. Create a JTable based upon the data

For example:

```
Object[][] tableData = new Object[names.length][1];
for ( int i = 0; i < names.length; i++ ){
    tableData[i][0] = names[i];
}
Object[] colnames = {"MyColumnNmae"};
JTable table = new JTable(tableData, colnames);
```

You can alternatively:

1. Create a JTable based upon a [DefaultTableModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html) constructed with the same data (facilitates modifications)
2. Use the String array directly to create a [JList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html)

Comment: Or extend AbstractTableModel